# How to remove skid marks from fabric

Tags: tire, cleaning, clothing-care

What is an effective yet safe way to remove skid marks from fabric originating from keeping a bicycle on it?-- The back tire of my bicycle has been standing on a piece of rug and I need to clean the rug now (I didn't know I should have kept the rug clean until it was too late):

[image: Rug with skid marks]

Comment: In the future, it helps to take a wet sponge and just wipe your tire down if you know its going to be touching anything stainable.

Comment: A commercial carpet cleaning service might be your best option.  As long as they're not cowboys, they know all the little tricks for corner cases like this.   Personally I'd avoid heat, and flush with lots of water and use a water vaccuum to suck it up.  Repeat, repeatedly.

Comment: First vacuum, to remove any loose dirt before you grind it in by scrubbing.  Then try scrubbing with a mild detergent.

Comment: http://deadspin.com/i-have-skidmarks-what-to-do-1054235836 ;)

Comment: Such a misleading title.. lol

Comment: @Criggie, in the end I had to take it to a carpet cleaner's after all; If you create an answer out of your comment, I'll accept it for you.

Comment: Note that these likely aren't "skid marks" (of either kind), but are places where oils from the tire have transferred to the carpet fibers, over a period of hours.  The way to avoid it is to place something under the tires when parking the bike.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a similar situation - bike tire marks, trainer residue and grease spots on the carpet - we found that scrubbing the carpet using a concentrated dish detergent (like Dawn, etc) worked very well.

Comment: This did help some, but unfortunately it didn't get it out all the way.

Answer (score 0):

My husband's bike left a large tire mark on a nice chair of our, and Dawn got most of it out - so much so that you can't notice it. Since I know it's still there, I am going to do a second cleaning, and I am certain that will do the full trick. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: This simply repeats the existing answer.